# How to display font as selected colour using javascript?

Tags: javascript, fonts, colors

I have a div that displays a font when selected and you hit the create button. I want to make it so when i select a specific colour from the drop down list the font is displayed in that color. Here is the html color form:

```
<div class="formbox">
                <label for="colourSelect">Your Colour:</label>
                <select name="colourSelect" id="colourSelect">
                    <option value="X">Chooose a colour</option>
                    <option value="R">Red</option>
                    <option value="O">Orange</option>
                    <option value="Y">Yellow</option>
                    <option value="G">Green</option>
                    <option value="B">Blue</option>
                    <option value="P">Purple</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Here is the javascript I am using to display the font.

```
function fonts(){

if(wholeForm.normal.checked == true){
document.querySelector("#display").style.fontFamily = 'AmbleRegular';

}

if(wholeForm.normal.checked == true){

    document.querySelector("#display").innerHTML = "Normal";

}
}
```

Comment: `style.color` is the property for changing the text color. Have you tried that? Your question is a bit unclear about *what* you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, essiantly I have a display div that displays a selected font(that are selected using radio buttons) after hitting the submit  button. And now I just want to select a colour from the list and then when I display the font it should appear as whatever colour i have chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Use onchange for the dropdown and pass the argument to the javascript using this.value

Sample Code: `onchange="fonts(this.value)"`

In the Javascript, Write your condition like this

```
var color;
if(value=="R"){
   color=Red
}
if(value=="Y"){
   color=Yellow
}

document.querySelector("#display").style.color=color; //assign the color here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a listener:

If our HTML is, say:

```
<select id="colorSelect" onChange="update()">
    <option>red</option>
    <option>blue</option>
</select>

<div id="text">My text</div>
```

Then we could use a script that will run a function when the value of the select changes.

```
var select = document.getElementById("colorSelect");
var text = document.getElementById("text");

function update(){
    text.style.color = select[select.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function kk(){

var aa = document.getElementById('colourSelect');
var gg = document.getElementById('txt')
var bb = aa.options[aa.selectedIndex].text

switch(bb){

case "Red" : aa.style.color = "red"; // this will change color of txt inside <option>
break;

case "Orange" : gg.style.color = "orange";//this will change color inside <p>
break;

case "Yellow" : aa.style.color = "yellow";
break;
}
}
</script>
<div class="formbox">
                <label for="colourSelect">Your Colour:</label>
                <select name="colourSelect" id="colourSelect" onchange="kk()">
                    <option value="X" >Chooose a colour</option>
                    <option value="R" >Red</option>
                    <option value="O">Orange</option>
                    <option value="Y">Yellow</option>
                    <option value="G">Green</option>
                    <option value="B">Blue</option>
                    <option value="P">Purple</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Will change color